# Voting system java, declaring a winner

Tags: java, integer

I am not certain how to compare to different integer values and print which is biggest.

I am a new coder doing my first year at University, I am currently working on a simple voting system for my "Programming 1" class. I have pretty done the code (although improvement should probably be made). I want to declare a winner in my voting system when the vote has ended. I have a vote method which increments the values of `candidate1Votes` and `candidate2Votes` and I then calculate it to see the overall percentage. How would I compare the voters values against each other to see which one has won and then return and print that as a message. Sorry for the inconvenience but I just started out.

```
        double totalVotes;
        double candidate1Share;
        double candidate2Share;

        totalVotes = candidate1Votes + candidate2Votes;
        candidate1Share = (candidate1Votes / totalVotes) * 100;
        candidate2Share = (candidate2Votes / totalVotes) * 100;


        System.out.format("CANDIDATE " + candidate1 + "\n recieved %1.1f percent of the votes\n", candidate1Share);
        System.out.format("CANDIDATE " + candidate2 + "\n recieved %3.1f percent of the votes\n", candidate2Share);
```

I am curios how you would move forward and compare the two different value to see which one has won (the biggest value) and then print that in a method.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is something called an `if statement`. I will not solve your homework for you, but here is a helpful resource.

```
  int x = 30;

  if( x < 20 ) {
     System.out.print("This is if statement");
  }else {
     System.out.print("This is else statement");
  }
```

This will print: `This is else statement` because x is NOT less than 20.

Using an `if statement` you should be able to solve your homework.

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method like this:

```
public void declareWinner(double voteCount1, double voteCount2) {
    if (voteCount1 == voteCount2) {
        System.out.println("Tie");
    } else if (voteCount1 > voteCount2) {
        System.out.println("Winner is candidate 1");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Winner is candidate 2");
    }
}
```

You can either invoke this method from your code, or use the contents of this method directly in your code.

To learn more about Java if conditions, refer the following documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Good luck with college.

Comment: Thanks for the help!